# How do you view memory in supporting libraries

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to troubleshoot a memory leak, but when I break execution and take a snapshot, the only memory that is shown is memory held by my code (unchecking the box "Show Just My Code" doesn't help because that only removes items like .net objects, but those objects are still created in my code). I suspect that the memory leak is in a managed library that I'm using, but as far as I can tell the snapshot does not include memory used internally by that library. When I hit a breakpoint and take a memory snapshot the `Process Memory (GB)` chart is showing something like 10gb used, but the snapshot shows a heap size of only 1.5 to 2gb. Are there settings in VS 2022 that I am missing that allow you to snapshot managed memory usage of supporting libraries?

***EDIT:***
After some more testing, it's looking like it's not really a memory leak, but instead the garbage collector is being slow to clean up dead objects. In one instance there was 2gb in the heap memory, but if I checked the box to "show dead objects" the total memory used went from 2gb to around 10gb, so 8gb was apparently just dead objects that hadn't been garbage collected yet. If I can't find good answers for that problem, I may ask a different question related to that. I think this question is still a valid question, but I'm not sure how much is actually being used by the managed library internally, but it's a lot less than I was originally thinking, and I am using some native libraries, so the unaccounted for memory may be native memory.